# How to include multiple rows in a table Bootstrap

Tags: html, html-table, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to construct a table on a website. Originally, I was using the standard text editor in DNN (DotNetNuke). However, my first question is how I would include multiple line items between each  and . My intended end result is at the bottom. Pardon me if this is a bit vague. When I go to https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_tables.asp, I find only a few styles of table and thought that condensed is the best one for this job.

Below is some sample code from W3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_table-condensed&stacked=h)

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Table</h2>
<p>The .table-condensed class makes a table more compact by cutting cell 
padding in half:</p>                                    
 <table class="table table-condensed">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Anna</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Debbie</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

xyz                                          abc
Current Release (linked to a document)       Current Release
November 2016                                January 2017
```

Comment: So, what you're asking is how to get your text into the table? As it stands now I cannot help. You've given your expected result, but not what's wrong with the current one.

Comment: When I add something in between the <td> and </td> elements, it puts it to the right of the previous text such as xyz   current Release.

Comment: That's because <td> is a table cell, encapsulated in <tr> (table row). Multiple <td>s make up one row. Fill it in as if you're reading from left to right (`<tr><td>xyz</td><td>abc</td></tr>`)